# How to find string between two "/" characters - php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

What I'm trying to do is edit the value of a folder when the title is changed. The title is directly associated with the folder and as such, for consistency, the folder needs to be updates.

What I have pre-stored so far is:

```
Pictures/Title/image.png
```

What i want to do is get out "Title" which will always be between two / characters. Then take that out of the string and replace it with the new title.

preg_match is the obvious function, but i'm unsure of how to use it to find and return the string I want.

```
preg_match("$title" , $ImageLocation, $matches);
$title = $matches
```

Ideally, that would work if i knew what the title would be but I can't figure out how to both account for the unknown string, and for the special characters.

All i know for certain is that "title", whatever that may be, will be between two "/" characters. The php docs show the use of special characters but i personally cannot fathom how to use the commands as it doesn't appear to be specific. Any help's appreciated.

Comment: `preg_match("#/$title/#" , $ImageLocation, $matches);`

Comment: As i said though, i do not have $title - i was just using it as a placeholder to represent ../title/.. in the stored location. Would that output $title via $matches?

Comment: Try Exploding with **'/'**, you will get all 3 strings in Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the folder structure remains the same, you can avoid Regexes and do

```
<?php
$title="Pictures/Anything/image.png";
$parts=explode("/",$title);
echo $parts[1];                          //Anything
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/281560)**

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thanks very much! Much easier than trying to understand the regex commands too.